# Getting overlay after login in Open Source Point of Sale

Tags: point-of-sale

I've installed Open Source Point of Sale in my system and followed the instructions mentioned. After logging in I'm getting a overlay on my home page and unable to perform any operation.

I've found the same [issue](https://github.com/jekkos/opensourcepos/issues/856) but no solution provided there.

I'm attaching the image ref:

[image]

Comment: Hi,
I am only suggesting you to use Odoo POS.
It is also open source platform.